# StaleElementReferenceExeption при попытке определить и кликнуть определенный результат поиска гугла

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Добрый день.

На странице результатов гугла по запросу "habrahabr.ru" хочу кликнуть именно на результат хабра.

Вариант "Кликнуть первый результат" не подходит.

Пытаюсь написать так, чтобы нужная линка нажималась при любой позиции в результатах поиска.

Метод clickLinkByHref(), приведенный ниже, приводит к

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference is stale. Either the element is no longer attached to the DOM or the page has been refreshed.

```
public static void clickLinkByHref() {

    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for ( WebElement link: links) { 

     if(link.getAttribute("href").contains("habrahabr.ru")) {
         link.click();
         break;
        }
    }
};
```

На стэке нашлось решение пробовать стучаться в линку через while, пока селениум ее не увидит:

```
    public static void clickLinkByHref() {

    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

    for (WebElement link : links) { 

         if(link.getAttribute("href").contains("habrahabr.ru")) {

             int attempts = 0;
             while(attempts < 5) {
                 try {
                     link.click();
                     break;
                 } 
                 catch(StaleElementException e) {}

             }
         }
    }
};
```

В результате уткнулся в это и застрял:

> StaleElementException cannot be resolved to a type

Помогите, пожалуйста. 
Спасибо